# Most efficient way to convert float 16ths to 4 bit integer in C

Tags: c

As part of an anti-aliasing routine I'm running on an STM32 (single precision FPU, if that matters), I'm looking to convert a float value 0 ≤ x < 1 to a 4 bit nibble representing opacity. Basically each LSB of the nibble corresponds to a 16th of the float, so 0 ≤ x < 0.0625 would be 0x0, 0.0625 ≤ x < 0.125 would be 0x1, so on. Are there any bit manipulation tricks I could use to make this operation fast/efficient?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean, I've tried a traditional switch-case statement, but I can't imagine that's the most effective way. 16 conditionals per pixel is pretty rough

Comment: What would you think would happen if you multiply x by 16?

Comment: I guess you could read it as a `uint32_t`, right shift 20 (discarding most of the mantissa), do a bit of range checking (and special case for 0), and a table lookup.

Comment: Target variable is 4-bits = 16 possible values. Assuming the float will always be between 0 and 1, multiply it by 16 and then round.

Comment: @AdrianMole you'd add 4 to the exponent bits, no?

Comment: @SamForbis No need to round - just truncate towards zero, assuming 0 <= x < 1.

Comment: Possibly! But, as @SamForbis says, the float value can be rounded or truncated to a byte and that will have the correct value in its lower nibble.

Comment: That sounds a bit more efficient, any idea why this is getting downvoted so much? I thought it was a fair question that hadn't been asked before

Comment: I can't speak for the down-voters, but the close-voters are citing "Needs more focus," which is implying that you should show something that you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any floating-point value, `x`, such that `0 <= x < 1`, the value `y = x * 16` will give `y <= 0 < 16`. Casting this `float` value to an `unsigned char` will set the lower nibble of that byte to the number of 16<sup>th</sup>s. Thus:

```c
float x = 0.51;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char)(x * 16);
```

Then `b` will have the value `0x08` - representing eight sixteenths; and likewise for any other (valid) value of `x`.

Comment: The multiplication by 16 might well be fast, because its a power of two and will just add 4 to the binary exponent of the float. Who has doubts should do some benchmark - on the target system.